# XNA Nuclex Spritefont Framework and Spritefont Textures

Tags: c#, xna, spritefont

The way XNA 4.0 render fonts on the screen is a step back from XNA 3.1, to say the least. Thankfully, using the [Nuclex Framework](http://nuclexframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sprite%20Fonts&referringTitle=Nuclex.Fonts) has solved this problem. However, this is for spritefont files.

Is there a way Nuclex can support spritefont textures([Nubik's](http://www.nubik.com/SpriteFont/), etc...) as well? If not,
how do you take "not-so-common" font, convert it to a spritefont, and make sure it's displayed on another computer(which probably won't have that font installed)?

Answer (score 1):

**Spritefonts are compiled**. You get a `spritefont.xnb` file when you build your content, and this file contains all of your characters (the ones you defined in the .spritefont file). Since **the game uses the characters that are in these files** - which get deployed with your game - there is no need for the target computer to have any fonts.

Also, there is **no need for Nuclex to support spritefont textures** - you can use these textures in your content as they are because **they will remain unchanged**. Nuclex fonts only use a different way of *drawing* characters than the default XNA Spritefont processor does. The spritefont texture characters are **already drawn**.